# Coffescript testing catch ajax calls

Tags: testing, coffeescript, sinon

I am trying to test come coffeescript class and I have problem with ajax calls. For example in coffee I get some data from server using $.getJSON. How can I catch this request or redirect to some fake server on my test? I've read something about sinon fakeServer and I tried something like this:

```
describe "TestClass", ->
  describe "#run", ->
    beforeEach ->
      url     = "/someUrl'
      @server = sinon.fakeServer.create()

      $ =>
        @server.respondWith("GET", url,
         [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                                    '{}'])

      @entriesDownloader = new TestClass().run()
```

But It don't work. In method run I call API using jquery. How to catch this request and return some mock. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just stub the `$.getJSON` method without the need for a fake server. For example:

```
sinon.stub($, 'getJSON').yields({ prop: 'val' });
```

Or, if you want to stub the behaviour for only certain urls:

```
sinon.stub($, 'getJSON').withArgs('/someUrl').yields({ prop: 'val' });
```

The method can be restored at any point using `$.getJSON.restore()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're missing the callback spy. And you don't seem to be running any tests, just the `beforeEach`. This is the example from the documentation and it follows the typical pattern of AAA: Arrange, Act, Assert:

```
server = undefined
before ->
  server = sinon.fakeServer.create()

after ->
  server.restore()

it "calls callback with deserialized data", ->
  callback = sinon.spy()
  getTodos 42, callback
  server.requests[0].respond 200,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  , JSON.stringify([
    id: 1
    text: "Provide examples"
    done: true
   ])
  assert callback.calledOnce
```

That `assert callback.calledOnce` is very important. Another handy function is `calledWith`, like so: `callback.calledWith(1, 2, 3)`. Use that one to make sure that your code is passing the right arguments to an external function when you pass a known set of arguments in to the tested function.